# redirect url to another url in tomcat 7

Tags: tomcat

I am using Tomcat 7 which have 3 applications in its `webapps` (`app1, app2, app3`). My problem is with `app3` which is no longer in use now and I want to redirect it to another url.

Like,

when user hits `http://public_ip:8080/app3`. It should be redirected to another url: `http://domain-name` (which is another server) where `app3` is deployed.

Note:

1. I cannot use `Apache` web server due to some reasons.
2. I have no issue if my url `http://public_ip:8080/app3` appears to be changed in `http://domain-name` in browser.
3. `app1` and `app2` should run as it is, on the url: `http://public_ip:8080/app1` and `http://public_ip:8080/app2` respectively.

OS: RHEL 6.5

Comment: You may be able to deploy another application at the /app3 URL, and have that application send a redirect to the client. This answer from SO has some details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1363781/6216002

Comment: Thanks @Haxiel. Link you provided resolved my problem.